# How to in-memory unit test Spring-Jersey

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm working with Spring-Jersey3 and cannot figure out how to unit test the RESTFul API with Spring beans

Controller

```
package com.controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.service.DataSource;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("test")
@Component
public class SpringController {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getHello() {
        return new String(datasource.load());
    }
}
```

Service Interface

```
package com.service;

public interface DataSource {
    public String load();
}
```

Service Implementation

```
package com.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class DataSourceImpl implements DataSource {

    @Override
    public String load() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

ResourceRegister.java (Jersey resource register)

```
package com.component;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import com.controller.SpringController;

public class ResourceRegister extends ResourceConfig {

    public ResourceRegister () {
        register(SpringController.class);
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
  <param-value>com.component.ResourceRegister</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Jersey</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

serviceContext.xml (Application Context)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />

</beans>
```

Unit test <<-- I really have no Idea how to test this

```
public class test extends JerseyTest {
    public test() {
        super("com.service", "com.controller");
    }

    @Override
    protected AppDescriptor configure() {
        return new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("com.service","com.controller")
               .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:serviceContext.xml")
               .contextPath("/rest")
               .servletClass("org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class")
               .initParam("javax.ws.rs.Application", "com.component.ResourceRegister")
               .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Client client = new Client();
        WebResource resource = client.resource("test");

        ClientResponse response = resource.post(ClientResponse.class);

        assertEquals(200, resposne.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Project [Source Code](https://github.com/Mrshll187/SpringJersey)

**Problem : Dependency injection returns null**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**A few things I would fix:**

- You are using Jersey 1.x flavored Jersey Test Framework, but your app is Jersey 2.x. See below for 2.x dependency.
- I've never used the Jersey 1.x flavored Test Framework, but with Jersey 2.x, the [In-Memory container](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html#d0e16898) doesn't support servlet dependent features. See below for different dependency.
- With Jersey Test Framework, you do not need to create the `Client` yourself. There is one created, and we can simple call `JerseyTest`'s `target(String path)` method to get back a `WebTarget` (Jersey 2.x, `WebResource` is Jersey 1.x)

Here is a refactor that works.

Dependency (I only added this dependency, and didn't take anything out, as your GitHub project didn't include anything test related, as your code example above does)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Test

```
import com.component.ResourceRegister;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.DeploymentContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.ServletDeploymentContext;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.spi.TestContainerFactory;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;

public class SpringTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return new GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment(){
        return ServletDeploymentContext
                .forServlet(new ServletContainer(new ResourceRegister()))
                .addListener(ContextLoaderListener.class)
                .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String response = target("test").request().get(String.class);
        Assert.assertEquals("Hello", response);
        System.out.println(response);
    }  
}
```

For those not use an xml context file, you can use an annotation config application context, and add it as an init param

```
return ServletDeploymentContext
        .forServlet(new ServletContainer(new ResourceRegister()))
        .addListener(ContextLoaderListener.class)
        .initParam("contextConfig", new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(YourSpringConfig.class))
        .build();
```

**Other Resources:**

- [Jersey Test Framework Documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html)
- [More examples from Test Framework source code tests](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/test-framework/providers/grizzly2/src/test/java/org/glassfish/jersey/test/grizzly/web). (Hint: the link I provided is for grizzly web container examples, but if you traverse back to [providers](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/test-framework/providers), you can look at each provider and go to the test packages for examples for those providers)

---

## UPDATE

So after a few more test, here are a couple interesting things I discovered

### One:

With the above dependency, even if we don't configure the `DeploymentContext`, and just override `Application configure()` in the `JerseyTest`, it will still work. Can't really explain it, but it appears the descriptor is still picked up.

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SpringTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    public Application configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig().packages("com.controller");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String response = target("test").request().get(String.class);
        Assert.assertEquals("Hello", response);
        System.out.println(response);
    }  
}
```

### Two:

Even if we get rid of the above dependency (grizzly) and use the in-memory dependency, the same simple previous test works. The documentation states

> In-Memory container is not a real container. It starts Jersey application and directly calls internal APIs to handle request created by client provided by test framework. There is no network communication involved. This containers does not support servlet and other container dependent features, but it is a perfect choice for simple unit tests.

So I am not completely sure what Servlet features they are referring to, as this test still works

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
</dependency>
```

What I don't understand in particular, is this statement

> "There is no network communication involved"

because when I run the test, I see a log

> `INFO: Creating InMemoryTestContainer configured at the base URI http://localhost:9998/`

Comment: So I'm trying to figure out where this overridden method is coming from     DeploymentContext configureDeployment(). I've bumped several version of JerseyTest framework and cannot find where this method is coming from

Comment: I would get rid of all the Jersey related dependencies that aren't `org.glassfish.jersey`. My Guess is you are still using the older `JerseyTest` which doesn't have that method.

Comment: And I will agree - this testing framework does some crazy magic behind the scenes