# Set baseUrl for JerseyTest when using InMemoryTestContainerFactory

Tags: java, junit, jersey, jersey-test-framework

I am new to `JerseyTest`. I have created a few unit tests for my controllers by following the numerous posts on the subject as well as the various questions on this site. I am using `InMemoryTestContainerFactory` as my tests are very simple. However, there does not seem to be a way to set `baseUri` during set up. What do I set my target to? My test classes extend the following class:

```
public abstract class ApiTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
        return new InMemoryTestContainerFactory();
    }

    @Override
    protected ResourceConfig configure() {
        ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig()
                .register(SpringLifecycleListener.class)
                .register(RequestContextFilter.class)
                .register(this)
                .property("contextConfig", new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfiguration.class));

        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
        forceSet(TestProperties.CONTAINER_PORT, "0");

        return configure(rc);
    }

    protected abstract ResourceConfig configure(ResourceConfig rc);
}
```

Sample test class:

```
public class ResourceTest extends ApiTest {

    private final Client webClient = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    @Rule
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Mock
    private ResourceService service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResourceConfig configure(ResourceConfig rc) {
        rc.register(Resource.class);
        return rc;
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetResource() {

        Response response = webClient
                .target("http://localhost:8080")
                .path("/resource")
                .queryParam("id", "some_id_json")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                .get();

        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST));
        assertThat(response.readEntity(Errors.class).getMessages().get(0), isA(String.class));
    }
}
```

None of the sample code available on this site seem to be configuring the `baseUri`(see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28620966/341008) for example). And yet, if I set it to some arbitrary value `http://localhost:xxx` I get connection refused (obviously?). If I set it to just the path, I get the error `base URL is not absolute`.

Answer (score 1):

You can override `URI getBaseUri()` in the `JerseyTest`. The default is `localhost:9998`

But you don't really need to use this. `JerseyTest` already has a `Client` *and* `WebTarget` (built from `getBaseUri`) set up for you. All you need to call is `target` to get it, e.g.

```
Response response = target().request().get();
// or
Response response = target("path").request().get();
```

Comment: The first gives me a `NullPointerException`. The second complains that URL is not absolute. I can see that the base URI is set to `http://localhost:0`. I am guessing the problem is with setting up the container.

Comment: I have been searching for an hour to find the answer to this question; the Secret of Port 9998 is well hidden and appears to be missing from the JerseyTest official documentation page. localhost:9998 is the answer to the question and should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I had overridden setUp() without calling `super.setUp()`as a result of which `TestContainer.start()` was not being called.