# filenotfoundexception running jerseyTest - missing applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, jersey-test-framework

I'm running a test on Hello World trying to follow the Jersey Framework in my spring java program.

I have extended JerseyTest, but I'm getting the error above. The example Jersey gives [link](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/test-framework.html) doesn't seem to help.

```
public class SimpleTest extends JerseyTest {



@Override
protected Application configure() {
    return new ResourceConfig(RestService.class);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    final String hello = target("\service\hello").request().get(HelloModel.class);
    assertEquals("Hello World!", hello);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With Jersey 2.26 the dependency has changed to `jersey-spring4`, but to flush out the answer a little bit more if you **don't** want to spin up the entire Spring context.

Create the object:

```
    final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(restResource);
```

In my case, I just needed an empty context:

```
    final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    context.refresh();
    resourceConfig.property("contextConfig", context);
```

That was able to allow the `JerseyTest` to run successfully.

Comment: This doesn't work for me for some reason. Jersey test container still complains it cannot find `applicationContext.xml`. Only solution I found so far is to supply an `applicationContext.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to happen if you have the jersey-spring3 dependency. The default behavior is to look for this applicationContext.xml file (which is your Spring context configuration).

If you want to configure Spring for the test, you can do a couple things.

1. You could manually create the `ApplicationContext` and pass it to Jersey

   ```
   ApplicationContext context = ...
   return new ResourceConfig(RestService.class)
       .property("contextConfig", context)
   ```

   If you are using xml configuration, then you would create a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`. If you're using Java config, then you would create an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.
2. If you need servlet servlet container support, check out the example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28620966/2587435)

Comment: what would this be? AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(YourSpringConfig.class). I tried application and jerseyconfig, but they didn't work.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: I went to the link on number 2. I followed what they had on the learned lessons. I'm doing the .packages(com.service.rs) for the hello world. I'm getting the error NoClassDefFound on inject/Binder

Comment: I don't know. Maybe a problem with versions.

Comment: All my versions in the pom are 2.26-b09

Comment: 2.26 Changed injection. The packages are different. If you are trying to copy code, remove the imports and let your IDE auto-import them

Comment: Actually never mind, that would be a compile error. Most likely you have some dependency version problems

Comment: I have deleted them all. for imports, I have javax.ws.rs.core.Application;org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResurceConfig;org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;org.Junit.Test

Comment: Do you know all of the ones I need? I can just delete them all and readd them.

Comment: Update your post with your dependencies, and I'll take a look at it.